# C++ QT, emit signal from custom eventfilter failed

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot, eventfilter

I have a question about qt signal/slot and custom eventfilter.
usually, the default eventfilter is looks like "xxx->installEventFilter(this)".
I create a new class about custom eventfilter. It works well.
but, when I want emit a signal from it, it failed,  signal/slot not work.

bellow is some main codes about this:

### PlotsView.cpp

```
void PlotsView::createPlot()
{
         std::map<std::string, std::string> param_map =
         {
             {"tickerstr", 1234}
         };

         QHBoxLayout *candleplotlay = new QHBoxLayout();

         PlotCreatorDF  customcandle;
         QCustomPlot *candleplot;
         candleplot = customcandle.setupCandlestick(param_map);

         QObject::connect(&customcandle, SIGNAL(atesty(int)), this, SLOT(atestyy(int)));

         plotcontainerlay->addWidget(candleplot);

}


void PlotsView::atestyy(int x)
{
    qDebug() << "[CandleNewSecurity_List>>atestyy] x: " << x;
}
```

### PlotCreatorDF.h

```
class PlotCreatorDF : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit PlotCreatorDF(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~PlotCreatorDF();

    public slots:
        void atestz(int x);

    signals:
        void atesty(int x);

};
```

### PlotCreatorDF.cpp

```
    #include "PlotCreatorDF.h"
    #include "qcustomplot.h"
    #include "Plot/ploteventfilter.h"
    
    PlotCreatorDF::PlotCreatorDF(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
    {
    }
    
    PlotCreatorDF::~PlotCreatorDF()
    {
        qDebug()<<__LINE__<<__FUNCTION__;
    }
    
    
    QCustomPlot* PlotCreatorDF::setupCandlestick(std::map<std::string, std::string> param_map)
    {
    
        QCustomPlot *daily_plot = new QCustomPlot();
        daily_plot->setObjectName("test");
    
        //:
        PlotEventFilter *customfilter = new PlotEventFilter();
        daily_plot->installEventFilter(customfilter);
    
    
        connect(customfilter, SIGNAL(atestx(int)), this, SIGNAL(atesty(int)));
        connect(customfilter, SIGNAL(atestx(int)), this, SLOT(atestz(int)));
    
        return daily_plot;
    
    }
    
    void PlotCreatorDF::atestz(int x)
    {
        qDebug() << "[PlotCreatorDF>>atestz] x: " << "x";  //
    }
```

### customeventfilter.h

```
    #ifndef CUSTOMENTFILTER_H
    #define CUSTOMENTFILTER_H
    #include <QWidget>
    
    namespace Ui {
        class CustomEventFilter;
    }
    
    class CustomEventFilter : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
            explicit CustomEventFilter(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
            ~CustomEventFilter();
    
            bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *qevt);
        signals:
            void atestx(int x);
    
        private:
    };
    
    #endif // PLOTEVENTFILTER_H
```

### customeventfilter.cpp

```
    #include "customeventfilter.h"
    CustomEventFilter::CustomEventFilter(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent){}

    CustomEventFilter::~CustomEventFilter()
    {
        qDebug()<<__LINE__<<__FUNCTION__;
    }
    bool CustomEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *qevt){
    
        if (qevt->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) { //MouseButtonPress
            qDebug() << "[CustomEventFilter>>eventFilter] mouse clicked ... ";
            emit atestx(123);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The connection seems failed to create the connection, and the slot function atestz not work.

Can anyone help me, why and how, thanks!

---

very sorry, I have add some codes to make the question clearly.

I have to say all the connections in the code not work.

It seems that any signal can't be sent from "CustomEventFilter".

Comment: and where the function *PlotCreatorDF::setupCandlestick* is called:

Comment: You're trying to connect the signal `atestx` to another signal `atesty`: where is `atesty` declared?  Is that *really* what you want to do?

Comment: sorry, I will add and change some codes soon.